# Feature eliminaton of dummy variables

Tags: categorical-data, feature-selection, dummy-variable

I have several categorical variables with high number of classes. I used one-hot encoding in order to convert them into 1-0 format.

original:

```
column_1    column_2
0.8            X        
0.3            C        
0.9            D        
1.2            C
```

one-hot encoded:

```
column_1    column_2_X   column_2_C  column_2_D  
0.8            1            0           0
0.3            0            1           0
0.9            0            0           1
1.2            0            1           0
```

Then I checked feature_importances of them.

For example column_2_C has no importance to model, but others which share the same category(A) has significant importance.

In this case or any other case(%50 of the classes have high importance %50 of them are very low) what should I do? What if column_2_C has crucially significant but others (X and D) has no importance at all?

What happens if I remove that class? Any best practice for this kind of case?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the dummy variables in a model, then removing the non-significant variables or non-confounders is appropriate. However, if you are retaining the original categorical variable you should not delete those observations from your sample. I would need more information regarding what you are doing.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm trying to build a binary classification model, I have several numerical and categorical variables. Think that one of the categorical variable is chocolate brands. chocolate brand-A has significant importance according to model but chocolate brand-B has none. If I drop Chocolate_brand_B column is it appropriate?

Comment: Yes you can drop Chocolate_brand_B. Because Chocolate_brand_A still contains yes/no for your entire population, correct? Chocolate_brand_A significance means those that are a Brand A are more/less likely to have an outcome (what ever your outcome is) relative to those that are not Brand A. Hell, you can keep it and there might even be interactions with other variables you are exploring.

Comment: but what if Chocolate_brand_A doesn't contain yes/no for entire population, I mean what if there 50 different brands and only 10 of them has significant importance to model. In this case, is it appropriate to drop other 40 brands?

Comment: It depends how you created your dummy variables. Usually you create a dummy variable where the new variable is either 1/0 or yes/no for the entire population regarding the original value of categorical variable. Yes, it would be appropriate to drop other non-significant variables (depending on your definition of significance). What is your reference value for your dummy variables currently?

Comment: I use pandas get_dummies method, it converts all classes into 1/0 format, for same example it adds 50 columns for each chocolate brand name and flags whether it is used or not. I use feature_importance_ default function from xgboost with random variable. I create random variable and put it in evaluation, if any feature has less importance than random variable, it represents that these features are not important. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I personally filter variables out prior to modeling by looking at univariate statistics with each independent variable and the dependent variable. I use R. I look at each univariate p-value and determine on my own threshold I decide which variables to include in the initial multivariate models.